# Unfortunately, Software Update has stopped

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, updates, notifications, crashes

I have Android 4.1.2 installed on my phone, which is not rooted. It's stock Android (I'm not sure if 100.00% stock though). This is the first Software Update notification that I have ever received.

[image]

Whenever I click it, I get the "Unfortunately, Software Update has stopped" message and the app closes. I tried opening it from Settings, but the same behavior.

How do I apply the update, if it's actually available? Or if that's not possible, how do I remove this notification? Is the phone maker/vendor responsible for this error? This is my first Android phone. Any help please?

Comment: Which device do you have?

Comment: @Chahk I have Xolo Q800. Sorry but you might be unaware about this phone, since it's available only in my country. I just thought there would be a device-independent way of solving this. Is there?